# How to create host file with ansible with play hosts IP

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create a hosts file with following task. I am running this task on machines completely out of groups['hadoop']. Here I want to create hosts file for nodes from groups['hadoop'] without running my this play on groups['hadoop']

```
- name: Update /etc/hosts
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts
          regexp='.*{{ item }}$'
          line="{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{item}}"
          state=present
  when: hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address is defined
  with_items: groups['hadoop']
  tags:
    - etc-hosts
```

I tried this but it didn't work, it worked only when I have groups['hadoop'] in my play hosts.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible will detect facts like the IP through the setup module. This is by default executed as very first task of a play on those hosts which will be processed by the play. Therefore Ansible only knows facts about the hosts of the current play. Not part of the play -> no details available.

To solve this you have two options.

1) Add a play without tasks, just to run the setup module on the hadoop hosts.

```
---

 - hosts: hadoop
   gather_facts: yes

 - hosts: other hosts
   tasks: your actual tasks here

...
```

2) Enable [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching). Fact caching, as the name suggests, provides a way for Ansible to memorize facts about hosts it did not process in the current playbook. For this you will need to set up a redis instance locally or somewhere available on the network.